# Window Size is smaller than it should be

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Alright so I've got this JFrame with a screen on it. I've set the size to 800 by 800. However the window is created smaller than that. It's not a problem with the taskbar because it's not fullsize.

```
package sharph;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static String Title = "Game 1";

    public static Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(800,800);

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle(Title);
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Screen screen = new Screen();
        screen.setSize(screenSize);

        frame.add(screen);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In the screen class the paint method draws a box around where the border should be:

```
//Draw border
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawRect(1, 1, 799, 799);
```

When I run it, the window is smaller than the box and the bottom and right sides are cut off.

[image]
[image]

Note the second picture I manually re-sized to show the border difference.

I realize that I have drawn the box 1 pixel smaller on each side, but the difference is much more than 2 pixels.

Comment: 800*800 is the size with the window decoration (the frame and the title bar) not the size of the inner space.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `frame.pack()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the content needs to squeezed into the size of the frame minus its borders.

Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319) for a more detailed explanation

The layout manager is also overriding the size property you set on the `Screen` component. In either case, you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize` method of the `Screen` class

Also, you shouldn't be relying on magic numbers or assumptions about the actual size of the component, but should, instead, be using `getWidth` and `getHeight` instead (I know, it's just for demonstration purposes)

Comment: Thanks so much! And yes I'll change those.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "screen.setSize(screenSize);" type "screen.setPreferredSize(screenSize);" and then after you type "frame.setVisible(true);" type "frame.pack()". You can also remove "frame.setSize(screenSize);" if you want to.

Comment: You should, generally, pack the frame before making it visible, my cause repaint issues otherwise

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've never had any issues with that, but I suppose others could.