# Setting Java 2D drawing start after TitleBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-2d

I have stepped in working with Java 2D and initially i have been stucked how to shift my drawing location after Title Bar.
If i start drawing x,y (0,0). my Shapes are that is under Title bar hides.

Wha tis the best way to set the Drawing Location after Title Bar.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've overridden paint on a top level container, like `JFrame`?  This is your problem.  A `JFrame`'s decoration is actually painted inside the window.

You should create a custom component, say from `JPanel` for example, override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there.

You can then add this to your frame or replace the frames content pane.

Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

You can to a look at

- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)
- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)

For more examples...